# Sharply less regular cardinals in set theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, set-theory, soft-question, large-cardinals

If $\lambda<\kappa$ are two regular cardinals, then every locally $\lambda$-presentable category is locally $\kappa$-presentable. The analogous statement does not hold for $\lambda$-accessible categories, though. In the books by [Adamek-Rosicky](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/locally-presentable-and-accessible-categories/94CB48295B6AF097FC232313A57BDE17) and [Makkai-Paré](http://www.ams.org/books/conm/104/) a special relation $\lambda\vartriangleleft \kappa$ for this property is introduced. It holds if and only if for every set $X$ with $\# X < \kappa$ the partial order $P_{<\lambda}(X)$ of subsets of $X$ with $<\lambda$ elements has a cofinal subset of cardinality $<\kappa$.

Several properties are established (see also [MO/150305](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150305)) which help to study accessible categories. But in principle this relation between regular cardinals is a purely set theoretic concept. Therefore, I wonder if set theorists have actually considered to use this relation, and which applications outside of category theory and categorical logic are there.

Comment: There is a rich literature concerning generalized covering and dominating numbers, or generalized cardinal characteristics, to which this concept is related. For exampe, Levi's answer to the question to which you link points at one article.

Comment: I think this is basically what I was asking [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243434/on-the-cardinal-arithmetic-of-accessible-categories).

Comment: @Tim: Right! I didn't see see your question. Perhaps my question then can get closed as a duplicate. On the other hand, your question has no detailed answer.

Comment: Some interesting information about this relation is found in the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/324437/2362).